# How to get tweets author with tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

I have a twitter bot which auto enters twitter giveaways, but most giveaways you need to tag and friend or 2, 
 I have it so it follows, likes and retweets but i cannot get it to reply

```
if ("tag" in tweet.text or "TAG" or "reply"):
  try: 
     api.update_status('@' + tweet.author + '@example1, @example2')
  except Exception:
       pass
```

this does not work 
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use `tweet.author.name`. Here is an example from a recent retweeting bot I made.

https://github.com/Kamori/ValorantLFM/blob/master/retweeter/valorantlfm.py#L92

Comment: thank you,  now do you have any idea how to make these tweets replys, you helped me alot i now just need to figure out how to reply to their status tweets

Comment: You'll need to use http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.update_status and set the `in_reply_to_status_id` to the top tweet's tweet id

Comment: How do you do this in V2? Api with tweepy?